# Find who is connected to a Unix domain socket (Linux)

Tags: linux, unix-sockets

I have a Unix domain socket (for example `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`). I know there is open connection(s) to this socket thanks to `lsof -U` or `ss -xa` but I cannot find which process is connected to it.

How can I know which process at the other end?

Comment: If the other question is unclear, you should edit it. Duplicates should really be avoided to avoid duplicating effort. I've just added my own answer to the other question, I'm not going to copy-paste it here as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas what would you advice? SE blog says duplication is [quite good](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), and meta says [merging is no so easy](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-is-our-policy-on-merging-duplicate-questions). Original question is filled with OP explanations about him trying to find the answer. If I would merge, I would erase it all and replace it with my simple question. This is a little rude IMHO, so what do you recommend?

Comment: Note that's SO blog and stats.SE meta, that doesn't necessarily apply to unix.SE (you may want to raise the topic on unix.SE meta). You could leave your question here if you think people are more likely to stumble on it than on the duplicate, undelete your answer there, delete it here unless you're happy to synchronise both.